# Passing extra parameters to a callable object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I know that in Javascript you can add extra parameters to a function. For example;

```
function sum(){

var result = 0;
for(var i = 0;i<arguments.length;i++){
  result += arguments[i];
}
return result;
}
```

And then call `sum(1,2,3,4)`. Right now I'm using Phonegap and I would like pass extra parameters to a callable object. (Doing something similar to what I explained before.)

In Phonegap you can access the filesystem by doing this:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, fail);
function success(fileSystem){
//Do something
 }
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this?

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success(option1, option2), fail);
    function success(fileSystem){
    //Do something
      if(option1 > option2){
       //Do something even interesting
       }

     }
```

Since I'm new to both, Javascript and Phonegap I'm not sure if it is possible to do something like this. I would like to **avoid using global variables**.

Comment: What actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: Pass extra parameters to the function success. Or do something similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) { return success(fileSystem, option1, option2); }, fail);
    function success(fileSystem, option1, option2){
    //Do something
      if(option1 > option2){
       //Do something even interesting
       }

     }
```

m?

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is what i want to do, I'll give it a try and answer you asap.

Comment: @Tim S.: nope. `option1` may be a closure

Comment: @Zerkms Thank you very much, you answer is exactly what i was trying to do. I'm sorry i my question was not clear enought.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do something like encapsulate it all in a function

```
function doFileSystemStuff(option1,option2){
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, fail);
   function success(fileSystem){
      //Do something
      if(option1 > option2){
       //Do something even interesting
      }
    }
}
```

Then call it approproiately with `option1` and `option2`

Comment: This is a really nice solution, but I wanted to do something like @zerkms did. I'm sorry, my question may be not clear enought.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
function(option1, option2){ success(option1, option2)}, fail);
function success(fileSystem){
//Do something
  if(option1>option1){
   //Do something even interesting
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not.

Your success-handler is called in the function `requestFileSystem`. My guesses are that the function doesn't include any other parameters.

Since you don't want to use global vars, there's a solution in the middle: put everything in a function:

```
(function() {
    var option1 = 0, option2 = 1;

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, fail);

    function success(filesystem) {
        console.log(option1, option2); // will display 0 and 1
    }
})(); // calls itself

console.log(option1, option2); // undefined
```

That way you can still set `option1` and `option2, access them in your methods, without making them global!

Comment: why you do not encapsulate everything into one object?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
function getFileSystem() {

    //set your option1, option2
    var option1 = 1, option2 = 2;

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

      //Do something

      function innerSuccess(fileSystem, option1, option2) {
       //Do something even interesting

      }
    }, fail);

}
```